# alias directive on ports 80 and 443

Tags: apache, alias, httpd.conf, directive

I'm trying to get an alias directive to work the same whether someone is coming in on port 80 or 443, but I only have it working on port 80. In this case, `http://192.0.2.240/~abhc` works, but `https://192.0.2.240/~abhc` puts the following in ssl_error_log; it's obviously ignoring the directive.

```
[Tue Jun 17 19:25:10 2014] [error] [client 192.0.2.156] File does not exist: /var/www/html/~abhc
```

Here are the relevant parts of httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 192.0.2.240
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   Redirect permanent /psynet https://192.0.2.240/psynet
# Force HTTPS for one directory; this works.
   alias /~abhc /var/www/sites/~abhc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName 192.0.2.240
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   alias /~abhc /var/www/sites/~abhc
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/psy-freud.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/psy-freud.key
</VirtualHost>
```

In case anyone is curious as to why I'm doing this: this is the web server for a university academic department. My predecessor used local user authentication, and I'm moving to the university's central LDAP. The only problem: many people have been `http://dept.example.edu/~smith` forever, their LDAP uid is jsmith, and I don't want to change their URL. So in this case, jsmith is in the group smith, and he can log in as jsmith and work on content in /var/www/sites/~smith, which has g+w. This also allows for shared sites like ~somegroup to be accessed via individual credentials, not a shared password on a sticky note like my predecessor did.

Comment: If you look closely on the startup log you'll see that `VirtualHost *:443` should be `VirtualHost _default_:443`.

Answer (score 0):

Your port 80 is being used by the system.

1. In Windows  “World Wide Publishing Service is using this port and stopping this service will free the port 80 and you can connect Apache using this port. To stop the service go to the “Task manager –> Services tab”, right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop.
2. If you don't find there then Then go to "Run > services.msc" and again find there and right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop.
3. If you didn't find “World Wide Publishing Service” there then go to "Run>>resmon.exe>> Network Tab>>Listening Ports" and see which process is using port 80

[image]

And from "Overview>>CPU" just Right click on that process and click "End Process Tree". If that process is system that might be a critical issue.